# Write subprocess output to file when using python's popen without blocking main tool

Tags: python, subprocess, pyside

How can I make it so users can launch a subprocess tool, while still maintaining the ability to write the error log to a file?

Currently this tool will write the error output to a log file when the subprocess launches another python tool that errors. However the problem is that when users launch the subprocess it blocks the main window and freezes it until the subprocess is closed.

Simple just create these three python files in the same folder and run the mainwindow.py tool and click the run buttons. An error log is created in the same folder.

**tool_01.py creates error output**

```
import sys
import os
import fake #CAUSE ERROR LOG WRITE
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class ToolWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(250, 100)
        self.ui_Run = QtGui.QLabel("Second Tool")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui_Run)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ToolWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**tool_02.py runs correct**

```
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class ToolWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ToolWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(250, 100)
        self.ui_Run = QtGui.QLabel("Working Tool")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui_Run)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ToolWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**MainWindow.py**

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

################################################################################
# Main
################################################################################
class MainWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        self.ui_Run01 = QtGui.QPushButton("Run Tool 01 (CREATES ERROR)")
        self.ui_Run01.clicked.connect(self.run_tool_01)

        self.ui_Run02 = QtGui.QPushButton("Run Tool 02 (WORKING)")
        self.ui_Run02.clicked.connect(self.run_tool_02)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.ui_Run01)
        layout.addWidget(self.ui_Run02)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def execute_tool(self, filepath):
        exe = sys.executable
        process = subprocess.Popen([exe, filepath], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=os.path.dirname(filepath))
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        exitCode = process.returncode
        print 'output:', output
        print 'exit:', exitCode

        if exitCode != 0:
            self.logfile = os.path.abspath('log.txt')
            directory = os.path.dirname(self.logfile)

            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)

            with open(self.logfile, 'w') as f:
                f.write(output)

            print 'Log:', self.logfile
            return False

        return True

    def run_tool_01(self):
        self.execute_tool(os.path.abspath('tool_01.py'))

    def run_tool_02(self):
        self.execute_tool(os.path.abspath('tool_02.py'))


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you considered using threads?

Comment: Could you demonstrate how i could implement something like that?

Comment: I would like for the tool to still work if the main window is closed, the child should still remain open.